# How to combine 2 list in to 1 list and get unique names from both the child of this 2 list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a collection with 3 records in it:

```
Add=A1,A2,A3
Division=D1,D2,D3
Multiply=M1,M2,M3,A2

type=Add,Div,Multiply
names=A1,A2 etc...
```

Now I want to get all unique name of `Add` and `Multiply` in to single variable
and only list of names of Division in separate variable:

Expected output:

```
CombineList=A1,A2,A3,M1,M2,M3
DivisionList=D1,D2,D3
```

This is my query:

```
var TypesList = Ds1.Tables["dtSubVariant"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(r => r["Type"] + "")
    .Where(g => activeTypes.Contains(g.Key))
    .Select(g => new { 
        type = g.Key,
        names = g.ToList()
    }).ToList();

    var result = new
        {
            CombineList = (from t in TypesList
                           where t.type != "Division"
                           let name=t.names.Distinct()
                           select new 
                           {
                               names=name
                           }).ToList(),
             DivisionList = TypesList.Where(t => t.method == "Division")
                                     .Select(t=>t.names).ToList()
        };
```

But still I am getting 2 list in `Combine list` as below:

```
[0]:Add
    A1,A2,A3
[1]:
    Multiple
    M1,M2,M3,A2
```

Comment: `Add.Union(Multiply)`?

Comment: @PawełDyl or `Union` Instead of `Concat` which does the work of `Distinct`

Comment: @Learning - Do you think you could change the input data `Add=A1,A2,A3` to actual compilable C# code please? It makes it much easier to understand what you're asking and for us to craft an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After better understanding what Learning wants the following is the answer.
You want to group records in `rows` (in this example - in your code it is the `Ds1.Tables["dtSubVariant"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()`)
By something like the `grouping` list I've created. And then you want to have the distinct values of all the inner collections of each group:

```
List<dynamic> rows = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { Type = "Add", Values = new []{"A1","A2", "A3"} },
    new { Type = "Division", Values = new []{"D1","D2", "D3"} },
    new { Type = "Multiply", Values = new []{"M1","M2","M3","A1"} }
};

List<dynamic> grouping = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { Type = "CombinedList", Types = new [] {"Add", "Multiply"} },
    new { Type = "Division", Types = new [] {"Division"} }
};

var result = (from r in rows
              from g in grouping
              where ((IEnumerable<string>)(g.Types)).Contains((string)r.Type)
              group r by g.Type into rg
              select new
              {
                  Type = rg.Key,
                  Values = rg.SelectMany(item => (string[])item.Values).Distinct().ToList()
              }).ToList();
```

---

If you want a distinct list of `Add` and `Multiply` then use `Union`

```
List<string> Add = new List<string> { "A1", "A2", "A3" };
List<string> Multiply = new List<string> { "M1", "M2", "M3", "A2" };

var result = Add.Union(Multiply).ToList();
```

One can use `Concat` but that just adds puts the two lists together without removing duplicates

---

In the context of your code above, your problem is that each item in your `TypesList` has an inner collection - and you want that the merge of all those inner collection to be distinct. Use `SelectMany` and `Distinct`:

```
var combineList = TypesList.Where(t => t.type == "Add" || t.type == "Multiply")
                           .SelectMany(t => t.names)
                           .Distinct();
```

all together:

```
var result = new
{
     CombineList = TypesList.Where(t => t.type == "Add" || t.type == "Multiply")
                            .SelectMany(t => t.names)
                            .Distinct(),
     DivisionList = TypesList.Where(t => t.method == "Division")
                             .Select(t=>t.names)
};
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `Division` is already a List, if the user wants a `DivisionList` variable with possible duplicates removed. Then he can just call `List<string> DivisionList = Division.Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: Why cant i loop on to result obect??

Comment: @Learning - what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that as result is anonomous object so i cant loop on to it but i want to loop on result variable.Can you please tell me how to do it??

Comment: @Learning - edited the answer - is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry but in your combinelist you have only Add and multiple result.where as i want to have all result in my result object(Add,multiple,Division) and then i want to loop over final result object.

Comment: @Learning - Do you want to loop over result? That is not possible because it is not a collection. It is a type with 2 properties - which each of them is a collection

Comment: Any other workaround through which this can be done??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120570/discussion-between-gilad-green-and-learning).

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = new
            {
                CombineList = TypesList.Where( t => t.type == "Add")
                                        .Union(TypesList.Where( t => t.type == "Multiply"))
                                        .Select(a => new { names = a.name }),
                DivisionList = TypesList.Where(t => t.method == "Division").Select(t=>t.names).ToList()
            };
```

You can print output like

```
Console.Write("CombineList");
foreach( var item in result.CombineList)
{
    Console.Write(item.name + " ");
}
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.Write("DivisionList");
foreach( var item in TypesList.Where( t => t.type == "Division"))
{
    Console.Write(item.name + " ");
}
```

Comment: This create an anonymous object with two Properties `CombineList` and `DivisionList`. The OP states that he wants separate lists. He stated that he wants them *in seperate variable*

Comment: @user3185569 this is what OP is doing in question.

Comment: And it is one of the things he's doing wrong without him noticing that. When he said: *But still i am getting 2 list in Combine list*

Comment: @user3185569 Did you notice the type of two lists? its not `CombineList`, `DivisionList `.

Comment: In your code, `CombineList` is `IEnumerable` of some anonymous type. `DivisionList` is a List.

Comment: Now as result is anonomous object i cant loop on to it.So how can i loop over result object??

Comment: @Learning can you show me structure of `TypesList` class?

Comment: @Learning you can't loop through it because it is a class but you can loop on it's properties like `foreach(var a in result.CombinedList)`

Comment: Edited my question to include the query